# Date values getting cleared from object when returning

Tags: polymer, vaadin, polymer-2.x, vaadin-date-picker, vaadin10

I'm stuck in a strange situation where my data is getting lost while setting it to a object.
Will try to elaborate the situation.
    this.tempRenewals = this.findById(this.renewals,'id',21869);

```
findById(arr,searchBy,val){
    if(!val){
       return {};
    }
    if(arr){
       return arr.find(x => x[searchBy] == val);                    
    }
}
```

value of renewals object

> [{"id":21869,"benefitEndDate":"02/22/2019","premium":0,"enrollmentStatus":"INFORCE","policyId":"test21331","productType":null,"stEnrollmentId":null}]

After findById is evaluated, I get date values undefined. 
I get below value in tempRenewals.

> "{"id":21869,"premium":0,"enrollmentStatus":"INFORCE","policyId":"test21331","productType":null,"stEnrollmentId":null}"

After debugging got to know, its losing value after the below code is evaluated.

```
 this._setProperty(property, value);
```

in property-accessors.html(polymer\lib\mixins\property-accessors.html),
its getting called internally.

I'm using 2-way binding with vaadin-date-picker, which is actually causing issue.

```
<vaadin-date-picker value="{{tempRenewals.benefitStartDate}}"></vaadin-date-picker>
```

But I'm unable to identify how do I resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The way you use `this._setProperty(property, value);` is only if `property` property is defined as `readOnly`. So, If you want to set a property with a value. try to use `this.set(property, value);`.

Comment: this._setProperty(property, value); 
is called internally.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused due to **incorrect format of date** "benefitEndDate":"02/22/2019".
**Vaadin-date-picker** was not able to identify the date in this format causing it to set empty value, thus clearing out the value as it is two-way binding.